# What does max do on a list of sets?

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, max

[`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) takes an iterable parameter and will return the maximum value for the iterable. For integers this is obvious behaviour as it can just determine which number is largest. For characters it instead uses Lexicographic ordering:

```
>>> max("hello world!")
'w'
>>> 'w' > 'r'
True
>>> max("Hello World!")
'r'
>>> 'W' > 'r'
False
```

However, what does Python do with a list of sets? It's unclear how set's ordering works, though I believe it's just to do with length:

```
>>> set([1]) < set([5])
False
>>> set([1]) > set([5])
False
>>> set([1]) < set([1, 2])
True
>>> set(range(5)) < set(range(7)) < set(range(1000))
True
```

But that's not what produces the `max` value:

```
>>> max([set([1]), set([5]), set([2, 4, 7]), set([100000])])
set([1])
>>> max([set([]), set([11]), set([5]), set([2, 4, 7]), set([100000])])
set([11])
>>> max([set(range(45)), set(range(12)), set(range(100, 1260, 40))])
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44])
```

How is Python determining the `max` value in this case?

Comment: I dont know exactly but i think it may be comparing the `sets` hash

Comment: `a < b` is checking if `a` is a subset of `b` (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)) but I do not know about `max()`.

Comment: @DanielSanchez sets are an unhashable type (because they are mutable)

Comment: @khelwood, I was doing research, it is true, thanks friend :)

Comment: The `<`, `>` operators on sets check for subset inclusion. i.e. `a < b` means every element of `a` is contained in `b` (but not vice versa). So I think `max` will just return _some set_ from the collection that is not contained in any other set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<` is the proper subset operator in python. It is not comparing length.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset

`set([]) < set([11])` is True because the first is a proper subset of the second, but `set([11])` is not a proper subset of any of the later sets. The natural implementation of `max` uses `<`, so it's not too surprising for it to return `set([11])` here.

Comment: Aha, this is correct! If I adjust the sets it becomes more obvious: `>>> max([set([]), set([11]), set([11, 5]), set([2, 4, 7]), set([5, 11, 100000])])` results in `set([100000, 11, 5])`

Comment: *The natural implementation of max uses `<`* - actually it accumulates using the greater-than operator `>` ([source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1427)) so it is testing whether the next item in the list is a *superset* of the current maximum.

Comment: @ajcr I probably should have said "One possible implementation" instead. I could find no indication of the actually implementation of `max` in the Python docs, so I would assume that CPython's choice of `>` is largely arbitrary.

Comment: I agree; your answer and explanation is perfectly accurate (my comment was just intended as a pedantic footnote).